# Extracting the solutions from a complicated list

Tags: list-manipulation

The following produces a list of solutions for $n = 2$ to $n = 30$. Given this list, how do I extract combinations of the $n$ values and solutions to create a ListLinePlot?

```
expr[n_] := V1/4 + (f V1)/4 + 1/(4 (-1 + n) Gamma[1/2 (-1 + n)]^2) n^(1/2 (-3 - n)) (f V1)^(1/
    2 (-1 + n)) ((-1 + n) n^(3/2) V1^(3/2) Gamma[
     1/2 (-1 + n)]^2 (2 Sqrt[
       f] (-1 + n) (n/(f V1))^(n/2) - (1 + 
        n) (n/V1)^(n/2) Hypergeometric2F1[1/2 (-1 + n), -1 + n, n,
        1 - f]) - 
  2 (-1 + n)^2 Sqrt[n] (n/V1)^(n/2) V1^(3/2) Gamma[
    1/2 (-1 + n)] Gamma[(1 + n)/2] Hypergeometric2F1[n, (1 + n)/2,
     1 + n, 1 - f] + (-5 + n) V1 Gamma[
    1/2 (-5 + 
       n)] (n Gamma[(3 + n)/
        2] (2 (-1 + n) (n/(f V1))^((1 + n)/2) V1 - 
        f (-3 + n) (n/V1)^((1 + n)/2) V1 Hypergeometric2F1[-1 + 
           n, (3 + n)/2, n, 1 - f]) - 
     2 f (-1 + n) (n/V1)^((1 + n)/2) V1 Gamma[(5 + n)/
        2] Hypergeometric2F1[n, (5 + n)/2, 1 + n, 1 - f])); With[{V1 = 1}, r = Table[{n, f /. FindMinimum[expr[n], {f, 1}]}, {n, Complement[Range[2, 30, .1], {3., 5.}]}]];
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not quite sure which form you want. So I tried 2 cases. You could always do (I reduced the number of entries here).

```
V1 = 1;
r = Table[{n, z0 = FindMinimum[expr[n], {f, 1}]; f /. z0[[2]]}, {n, 
   Complement[Range[2, 3, .1], {3., 5.}]}]
```

This gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or

```
V1 = 1;
r = Table[{n, z0 = FindMinimum[expr[n], {f, 1}]; z0[[1]], 
   f /. z0[[2]]}, {n, Complement[Range[2, 3, .1], {3., 5.}]}]
```

Which gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Pick the list you want. `z0` in the Table is just a temporary variable, introduced to make it easy to manipulate the result, right inside the `Table` on the fly.